# How can I make a call from an activity different from MainActivity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Hi guys I'm new on android and I'm trying to make a call from my app to an example number. The snippet code to make a call is very simple but I don't know why if I the snippet is in a method on the main activity all it works well, but if it is in another activity it give me NullPointerException. This is my snippet:

```
public void prova3(){
    try{
    String url2 = "tel:33334444";
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(url2));
    startActivity(intent);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
10-10 12:12:54.566: W/System.err(30802): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-10 12:12:54.571: W/System.err(30802):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3532)
10-10 12:12:54.571: W/System.err(30802):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3493)
10-10 12:12:54.571: W/System.err(30802):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3735)
10-10 12:12:54.571: W/System.err(30802):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3703)
10-10 12:12:54.571: W/System.err(30802):    at com.example.findmyclients.Hide_Unhide.prova3(Hide_Unhide.java:162)
10-10 12:12:54.571: W/System.err(30802):    at com.example.findmyclients.Hide_Unhide$1.onClick(Hide_Unhide.java:55)
10-10 12:12:54.571: W/System.err(30802):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4654)
10-10 12:12:54.571: W/System.err(30802):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19438)
10-10 12:12:54.571: W/System.err(30802):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
10-10 12:12:54.571: W/System.err(30802):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-10 12:12:54.576: W/System.err(30802):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
10-10 12:12:54.576: W/System.err(30802):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
10-10 12:12:54.576: W/System.err(30802):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-10 12:12:54.576: W/System.err(30802):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-10 12:12:54.576: W/System.err(30802):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
10-10 12:12:54.576: W/System.err(30802):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
10-10 12:12:54.576: W/System.err(30802):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and the method of the button in the dialog:

```
package com.example.findmyclients;

import com.google.android.gms.internal.v;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;

public class Hide_Unhide extends Activity {

    LinearLayout barrainfo;

    ImageButton icotelefono;
    ImageButton icoemail;
    ImageButton icofacebook;
    ImageButton icotwitter;
    ImageButton icosito;


    ImageButton prova;

    public Hide_Unhide (View v){
        barrainfo = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.links_bar);         //tutta la barra
        icotelefono = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.telephone_icon); //pulsante chiamata
        icoemail = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.email_icon);         //pulsante nuova mail
        icofacebook = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.facebook_icon);  //pulsante facebook
        icotwitter = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.twitter_icon);     //pulsante twitter
        icosito = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.sito_icon);       //pulsante sito web


        /* * * * * Try share button * * * */
        /*******************************/

        ImageButton trysharebutton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.share_icon);

        trysharebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                prova3();


            }
        });

        /*******************************/
```

The method prova3(); is obviously on the same class of the dialog.
Thank you

Comment: Where you called this method? you need context if you called this on non-activity class.

Comment: post your logcat please

Comment: if I call from for example a button on the ActionBar, all it works, if I call from a button placed on a dialog ...give me exception... nullpointerexception for precision

Comment: Please post code of dialog's button, and logcat

Comment: ok I will edit my question

Comment: I added only the snippet of the button ...

Comment: What's line Hide_Unhide.java:162?

Comment: do your code in Oncreate method instead of constructor...

Comment: @MysticMagic this: startActivity(intent); into prova3()

Comment: @Cheerag interesting...I try

Comment: I moved all this

     ImageButton trysharebutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.share_icon);
     
     trysharebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bottone condividi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    //prova3();
    
    
    String url2 = "tel:33334444";
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(url2));
    startActivity(intent);
    
   }
  });


in the OnCreate but when I push the button it won't do nothing